# Rename folder created by TFS build agent for build

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am using Team Services (former Visual Studio Online) with an external build agent running on my VM in Azure. For each build definition I have it creates folder in _work folder. Those folder are just named 1, 2, 3 etc.

Is there a way to give them specific names? Ideally corresponding to the build definitions' names.

Comment: There isn't. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Because name of the build definition is more user friendly than just plain numbers

Comment: Users typically don't need to poke around in those folders and Windows has a 260 character file path length limit that's really easy to bump into in the context of a build.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to achieve this. You can submit a feature request on [VSTS User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services).