# How to change repository directory mapping on the private agent in VSTS / Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, tfsbuild, build-agent

I have installed an On-prem VSTS agent. Below is the directory structure:

[image]

How can I change the directory structure to include the name of my project instead if a number like 2,3,4,5?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename folder created by TFS build agent for build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618054/rename-folder-created-by-tfs-build-agent-for-build)

Comment: Besides the one-word answer ("**no**"), there's no good reason for them to have a different name. If you want build outputs, use the Publish Artifacts task. If you need to troubleshoot a build failure, the build log will show you the folder name. If you need to access a specific subfolder in the context of a build, there are built-in variables like `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`.

Comment: This still works for the agents I've installed in 2023. Don't forget to adjust the file: _work/SourceRootMapping/Mappings.json with the latest mapped directory number plus 1, in case you just want to assign specific numbers to your pipelines. I've also adjusted the TFS workspace mapping for my pipeline using visual studio / tf.exe, since it also should point to a different directory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The direct answer is NO.

For now, the working directory can **only use the increment number as the folder name.** And you can find in the `_work/SourceRootMapping/Mappings.json` file, it records last build time and folder number so that it will create an increment number for next folder. All that are creating and increase automatically, there is no way to change the folder for the build working directories.

I posted an user voice [Enable to specifying folder name before building/releasing on private agent](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/31997710-enable-to-specifying-folder-name-before-building-r) to suggestion add the feature to specify folder name. You can vote and follow up.

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to   _work/SourceRootMapping/

There will be a directory like below;

473cf3c6-2655-40be-a900-9f5b91ea5865/

Inside it will be different sub directories like this

_work/SourceRootMapping/473cf3c6-2655-40be-a900-9f5b91ea5865/124$ cat SourceFolder.json

```
{
  "build_artifactstagingdirectory": "2/a",
  "agent_builddirectory": "2", **------->**Change this to whatever you want**!!!**
  "collectionUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/#########/",
  "definitionName": "<****Name of your pipeline****>",
  "fileFormatVersion": 3,
  "lastRunOn": "09/12/2019 18:34:12 +05:30",
  "repositoryType": "Git",
  "lastMaintenanceAttemptedOn": "",
  "lastMaintenanceCompletedOn": "",
  "build_sourcesdirectory": "2/s",
```

You might have to search all the SourceFolder.json under different sub directories to find your pipeline("definitionName": "<**Name of your pipeline**>")

Comment: @toscanelli I didn't find any. But, it would be good to have one. Would save a lot of effort.