# Azure-devops: Share output from different agents running their own jobs

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a build with multiple jobs, where they depend on each other's output. But I also have multiple agents, which gives me the following issue:

If Agent1 runs Job1, Agent2 runs Job2, and Job3 requires the output from both Job1 and Job2, I can't access the files from just one agent, since they are located on different machines.

How do I make my jobs able to download the output of other agents?

I looked for the [workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#workspace) on MS Docs, but it doesn't describe how to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add more details on top of **JukkaK's** answer.

> I looked for the workspace on MS Docs, but it doesn't describe how to
>   handle this scenario.

The `workspace` is something corresponding to agents. No sure which kind of agent do you use, but different agents have different OS instance, so the content under same path(workspace) in one agent should be quite different from that in another agent.

So workspace is not the approach for you needs.

> How do I make my jobs able to download the output of other agents?

You can use `Publish Artifacts+Download Artifacts` combination to do what you need. See this:

[image]

You can place `Publish build Artifacts` task as the last task of agent job1 and job2. Then add a `Download buil Artifacts` as the first one of agent job3.

And make sure agent job3 depends on agent job1 and job2 like this:

[image]

In this way, the output from agent job1 and job2 can be installed in agent job3's machine for further usage. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Pipeline artifacts in multi-stage pipelines would be a perfect match for this, if the current features available with multi-stage pipelines otherwise satisfy your needs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

If not, the best I can come up with is directing the the jobs to same agent by adding a capability to agent and adding a demand to the pool-assignment (or by creating your own pool). With Deployment group agents, adding tags is a handy way to direct jobs to a certain agent in deployment group, but haven't found anything similar on build agents.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: The answers here: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46896763/how-to-change-repository-directory-mapping-on-the-private-agent-in-vsts/

are still valid enough and illustrate how build definitions/pipelines are mapped to certain agent's work directories. So your work directory might 10 in one agent and 25 in another - but if you direct build always to the same agent, I think (but not entirely sure) that different jobs use the same work directory. Pipeline artifacts would be better solution, though.